# HTML/PHP timings table funky layout

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to create a opening and closing time table for a compnay dynamically but the layout looks really bad as it has too much gap in between each row, this is a creen shot of it :[Screenshot](https://snag.gy/uHoMt8.jpg)

can anyone help me out s in why this is being caused or where i should place the php code to make it right.
Thanks in advance

```
    <div class="container about-timings wow fadeInUp">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <?php 

include("admin/db/db.php");



$select_db = "select * from timings";

$run_events = mysql_query($select_db);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run_events)){


    $id = $row['id'];
    $day = $row['day'];
     $open = $row['open'];
     $close = $row['close'];


?>
            <table class="table table-bordered">



                        <td><?php echo $day; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $open; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $close; ?></td>

<?php }?>

            </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
 <?php
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run_events)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $day = $row['day'];
     $open = $row['open'];
     $close = $row['close'];
    echo' <tr>
              <td>'. $day .'</td>
              <td>'. $open.'</td>
              <td>'.$close.'</td>
          </tr>';
 }?> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `flex` instead and set the flex items to `flex-grow: 1` or `flex: 1 0 0` for short.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  border: solid #aaa;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0;
}
.flex:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
}
.flex > div {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  padding: .5em;
}
.flex > div + div {
  border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="container about-timings wow fadeInUp">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

<?php 

include("admin/db/db.php");

$select_db = "select * from timings";

$run_events = mysql_query($select_db);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run_events)){

    $id = $row['id'];
    $day = $row['day'];
     $open = $row['open'];
     $close = $row['close'];
?>
      <div class="flex">
        <div>Monday - this is where you put php <?php echo $day; ?></div>
        <div>1:00 - this is where you put php <?php echo $open; ?></div>
        <div>2:00 - this is where you put php <?php echo $close; ?></div>
      </div>
      <!-- some additional sample output -->
      <div class="flex">
        <div>Tuesday</div>
        <div>1:00</div>
        <div>12:00</div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex">
        <div>Wednesday</div>
        <div>1:00</div>
        <div>12:00</div>
      </div>
      <!-- end sample output -->
      <?php }?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for you help, your code worked aswell but Mike's  code is what i wanted.  Appreciate it,Respect!